# Android: Disable setPositiveButton unless and until items are selected

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a code [posted in the body below ] which displays a list of items in an array list with OK and Cancel buttons. Basically i want to disable the OK button until a particular item is selected from the list. Could anybody let me know how i can do this for my code?

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    final CharSequence myList[] = { "Tea", "Coffee", "Milk" };
    ArrayList<Integer> selList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean bl[] = new boolean[myList.length];
    RelativeLayout rl;
    String msg ="";
    final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRL);
        final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
        ad.setTitle("What do you Like ?");
        ad.setMultiChoiceItems(myList,bl, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                if(arg2)
                {
                    selList.add(arg1);
                }
                else if (selList.contains(arg1))
                {
                    selList.remove(Integer.valueOf(arg1));
                }
            }
        });
        ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                msg="";
                for (int i = 0; i < selList.size(); i++) {

                    msg=msg+"\n"+(i+1)+" : "+myList[selList.get(i)];
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Total "+ selList.size() +" Items Selected.\n"+ msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)     
                        .show();
            }
        });
        ad.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You Have Cancel the Dialog box", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)     
                        .show();
            }
        });
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                msg="";
                ad.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the OK button from your AlertDialog using `getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)`. Modify the OnClickListener that launches the dialog so that you disable the OK button before you show the dialog:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        msg="";
        AlertDialog dialog = ad.create();
        Button okButton = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        okButton.setEnabled(false);
        dialog.show(); // call show on the AlertDialog, not the Builder
    }
});
```

I'm not sure of exactly what needs to happen for you to enable the button, but if it is response to the user selecting a particular item, then you should but the enabling code inside your OnMultiChoiceClickListener:

```
ad.setMultiChoiceItems(myList,bl, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
        if(arg2)
        {
            selList.add(arg1);
        }
        else if (selList.contains(arg1))
        {
            selList.remove(Integer.valueOf(arg1));
        }
        if ( /* YOUR CODE HERE */ ) {
            AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) arg0;
            Button okButton = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            okButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I tried what you have suggested, but my application crashes. I get a null pointer exception at this line:
final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

Comment: Hmmm. Try moving that line inside your onCreate function. The Builder objects are usually just temporary objects, that you don't need once you've actually created the dialog. If that doesn't work, then please post the stack from the crash so I can see what is null.